# i want to remove XML tags from an XML and send the data alone using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

i am looking to remove the XML tags from an xml and pass the data alone.

**input**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:mt xmlns:ns0="urn:upfield.poc.com:RestPolling"><data>
--BOUNDARY
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-length: 140
AppVersion=1.0&amp;amp;AcceptUPSLicenseAgreement=Yes&amp;amp;ResponseType=application/x-ups-pld&amp;amp;VersionNumber=V4R1&amp;amp;UserId=KPS001CA&amp;amp;Password=KPSS
--BOUNDARY
</data></ns0:mt>
```

**output**
--BOUNDARY
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-length: 140
AppVersion=1.0&amp;AcceptUPSLicenseAgreement=Yes&amp;ResponseType=application/x-ups-pld&amp;VersionNumber=V4R1&amp;UserId=KPS001CA&amp;Password=KPSS
--BOUNDARY

**I am trying this code but I am not getting the output. can you please suggest.**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
<xsl:value-of select="replace('<ns0:mt xmlns:ns0=', '')"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

"i am looking to remove the XML tags from an xml and pass the data alone.": the built-in processing rules will do that.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncntCSg